# Parsing HTML that is horribly structured?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, what I would like to do is create a Python function that allows me to pass it the year, month, and day of the podcast I'd like to download.  Then it would parse through the HTML and return the links for that day's podcast.  For example:

```
>>> get_download_links(year, month, day)
['https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44279&type=audio', # Hr 1 (audio)
 'https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44277&type=audio'] # Hr 2 (audio)
```

The page I'm trying to parse through is http://www.tytnetwork.com/annual-archives/2014-main-show-archives/

Here is an example of the first week of the month (including the weekday labels):

```
<tr>
           <th class="tytca-mosname" colspan="5">
            <h3>
             June 2014
            </h3>
           </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <th class="tytca-dayname">
            <h3>
             Mon
            </h3>
           </th>
           <th class="tytca-dayname">
            <h3>
             Tue
            </h3>
           </th>
           <th class="tytca-dayname">
            <h3>
             Wed
            </h3>
           </th>
           <th class="tytca-dayname">
            <h3>
             Thu
            </h3>
           </th>
           <th class="tytca-dayname">
            <h3>
             Fri
            </h3>
           </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td class="tytca-td">
            <div class="tytca-daynum">
             2
            </div>
            <p>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=42848&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=42851&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=42848&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=42851&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/02/tyt-june-2-2014-hour-1/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/02/tyt-june-2-2014-hour-2/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 2
             </a>
            </p>
           </td>
           <td class="tytca-td">
            <div class="tytca-daynum">
             3
            </div>
            <p>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43325&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43324&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43325&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43324&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/03/tyt-june-3-2014-hour-1/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/03/tyt-june-3-2014-hour-2/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 2
             </a>
            </p>
           </td>
           <td class="tytca-td">
            <div class="tytca-daynum">
             4
            </div>
            <p>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43635&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43633&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43635&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=43633&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/04/tyt-june-4-2014-hour-1/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/04/tyt-june-4-2014-hour-2/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 2
             </a>
            </p>
           </td>
           <td class="tytca-td">
            <div class="tytca-daynum">
             5
            </div>
            <p>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44046&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44044&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44046&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44044&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/05/tyt-june-5-2014-hour-1/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/05/tyt-june-5-2014-hour-2/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 2
             </a>
            </p>
           </td>
           <td class="tytca-td">
            <div class="tytca-daynum">
             6
            </div>
            <p>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44279&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-audio" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44277&amp;type=audio" title="Click to download audio file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44279&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/?tytpm=44277&amp;type=video" title="Click to download video file">
              Hr 2
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/06/tyt-june-6-2014-hour-1/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 1
             </a>
             <br/>
             <a class="tytca-video-watch" href="https://www.tytnetwork.com/2014/06/06/tyt-june-6-2014-hour-2/" title="Click to watch the video">
              Hr 2
             </a>
            </p>
           </td>
          </tr>
```

I've tried using beautiful soup, but the problem is that the page is so poorly structured, that there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want.

At this point, I'm turning this over to the Python gurus on here to help me.

Comment: I assume you have an account and you have already handled the authentication part?

Comment: @merlin2011 Yes, of course.  :D

Comment: Before "turning it over to the Python gurus": Please make the effort to construct a minimal example that can be run offline and contains only the relevant snippet of HTML you have trouble parsing, and your attempt at doing so.

Comment: @LukasGraf  I thought about it, but the HTML I need to parse is over 4,000 lines long (yes just the relevant parts), and the question is understood best with the graphical version of the site, not the HTML.

Comment: I get 403 forbidden when I try and go to http://www.tytnetwork.com/annual-archives/2014-main-show-archives/
 through anything other than a browser

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ya, they want you to send a useragent, I believe.

Comment: yeah I got it to work

Comment: @Soviero then *reduce* it to a minimal example that still has the same structure - only include two months, two weekdays, two rows of days to indicate the repeating patterns. Replace the rest with syntactically placeholders like `<!-- ... -->`. The link to the original source is still needed, but it's not enough.

Comment: @LukasGraf Done.  How's that?

Comment: @Soviero better, but it's not reduced, it's still full of redundant markup. And it doesn't contain your own attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4
import re
url = "http://www.tytnetwork.com/annual-archives/{year}-main-show-archives/"


def getPodCasts(m,d,y):
     my_url = url.format(year=y)
     print my_url
     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(my_url,headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content)
     calendar_row_for_month=soup.findAll(text=re.compile("^%s.*%s"%(m,y)))[0].parent.parent.parent
     for sib in calendar_row_for_month.findNextSiblings():
        if ">%02d<"%d in str(sib):
           break
     assert ">%02d<"%d in str(sib), "Error Date %s/%s/%s Not Found"%(m,d,y)
     audios = sib.find(text="%02d"%d).next.next
     return re.findall('https?:[^" ]*',str(audios))


print getPodCasts("June",12,2014)
```

Comment: Wow...  It's going to take me a week just to chew through all that and figure out what, exactly, it does.  Thanks!  ;)